# wpf обрезка изображения

Tags: wpf, изображения

```
<ListBox x:Name="addImageToRowListbox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding }" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                        Width="200"
                        Margin="3">
                <Image Source="{Binding imgsrc}" 
                       Stretch="Fill"
                      />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

в список попадают картинки с разным разрешением. мне нужно чтобы они обрезались до квадрата например 200х200 по центру как в галереях смартфонов. как этого достичь?

Comment: Попробуйте поместить Image в border, выравнять по центру и включить ClipToBounds у Border. У Image установить Stretch=None

Comment: @АндрейNOP сработало. но с дополнением: `Image Stretch="UniformToFill"`  и у Border ширина и высота по 200

Comment: Напишите ответом как получилось

Answer (score 1):

Помогла установка `Stretch="UniformToFill"` у `Image` и размеры 200х200 у `Border`
При этом широкие картинки подгоняются по высоте а по бокам обрезаются, аналогично с высокими

```
<ListBox 
     ItemsSource="{Binding }" 
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
     SelectionMode="Single">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>

            <Border 
                Width="200"
                Height="200"
                Margin="3" 
                ClipToBounds="True">
                <Image Source="{Binding imgsrc}" 
                       Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"

                      >
                </Image>
            </Border>
            <Button Content="Удалить" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Tag="{Binding imgsrc}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Если кому пригодится то такой же вариант с ItemsControl. Делал подобие папки с изображениями в Windows

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Border 
                    Width="200"
                    Height="200"
                    Margin="3" 
                    ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Image Source="{Binding imgsrc}" 
                           Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          >
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```